# Setting sampling rate of default audio output device programmatically

Tags: macos, core-audio, audiounit

I'm working on an application that plays sounds through the default audio device on a Mac. I want to change the output sampling rate and bit depth of the default output device but it always gives me a `kAudioUnitErr_PropertyNotWritable` error code.

Here is my test code:

```
    AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription newStreamFormat;
    newStreamFormat.mSampleRate = 96000;        // the sample rate of the audio stream
    newStreamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;     // the specific encoding type of audio stream
    newStreamFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;//kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonMixable;
    newStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    newStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    newStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 24;
    newStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
    newStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
    
    UInt32 size = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);

    result = AudioUnitGetProperty(myUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &streamFormat, &size);
    
    result = AudioOutputUnitStop(myUnit);
    result = AudioUnitUninitialize(myUnit);
    
    result = AudioUnitSetProperty(myUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &newStreamFormat, size);
    result = AudioUnitInitialize(myUnit);
    result = AudioOutputUnitStart(myUnit);
    
    result = AudioUnitGetProperty(myUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &streamFormat, &size);
    result = AudioUnitGetProperty(myUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &streamFormat, &size);
```

When I make the call to set the stream format on `kAudioUnitScope_Input` I don't get any error but when I set it on `kAudioUnitScope_Output` if fails with the property not writable error.

It must be possible to do this programmatically (Audio MIDI Setup does it) but I have searched and searched but I haven't been able to find any solution.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170523/coreaudio-audiounitsetproperty-always-fails-to-set-sample-rate) post that implies that setting the input sampling rate of the device will update the output as well. I tried this but when I read back the property the output doesn't match what I set on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not the output `AudioUnit`'s job to configure devices. It's more of an intermediary between clients and audio devices. Which means `AudioUnitSetProperty()` is the wrong API for the job.

So if you want to configure the device, try setting `kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate` on it using the `AudioObjectSetPropertyData()` function.

Then, unless you want a gratuitous rate conversion, you probably want to make sure your audio unit input format matches the new device sample rate by doing what you're already doing: calling `AudioUnitSetProperty()` on the input (data going into the audio unit) scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give it a try today and see what I get. Per your last comment, that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish here - matching the input sampling rate to the hardware. My code I have shown is just testing so I understand how all of this works. 

I'll post back my results

Comment: Yes - Setting the nominal rate through the AudioObjectSetPropertyData() works as you stated. The update is viewable through AudioMIDISetup application. Thanks for the answer.